# jQuery delegation or function method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Which method is faster and more supported among all browsers?
1. Writing a javascript function like:

```
function change_text(newtext) {

  $('div#id').text(newtext);

}
```

and appending it to an element's onclick event:

```
<button onclick="change_text('This is a new text');">Click Me</button>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ OR ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

2. Use delegation method like:

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
 newtext = $(this).attr('data-newtext');
 $('div#id').text(newtext);
});
```

and assigning a custom attribute:

```
<button data-newtext="This is a new text">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I always go with on, because then dynamically added DOM elements will still listen to the event. Also I find it clearer

Comment: You have to assign inline event handler to every element.whereas you can other one can operate on all elements

Comment: Me too, but is the delegation (on) method faster than the function method?

Comment: @user3382146 faster? Are you really worring here about nano seconds??? A click is following user interraction and no one on earth can click faster than handler get fired, no one except maybe Jon Skeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to go with `on` *and* make it even more decoupled:

```
<button id="theButton">Click Me</button>

function changeText(id, newtext){
    $(id).text(newtext);
}
function theButtonClick(){
    changeText('div#id','This is the new text' );
}

$(function(){
    $('#theButton').on('click', theButtonClick);
});
```

Leveraging jQuery's functionality is good since you let it handle cross-browser compatibility.